# playing video while encoding with ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

in my Webapplication the user should be able to upload his own videos (either format).
I am using ffmpeg to encode the video to .mp4 and .flv using the command:

ffmpeg -i uservid.whatever output.mp4 output.flv

while ffmpeg encodes the video, it's loaded in the flowplayer on the users-page. But flowplayer always says "file not found" cause ffmpeg is not yet finish with encoding.

Is there a possibility to load the video in a certain player even if it is not yet completly encoded? maybe there is a ffmpeg option?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

FLV yes, mp4 no. with flv you can have ffmpeg write to stdout and do whatever you need to with the output. mp4 requires a frame index (moov) that is not known until the entire file is encoded. flv encodes the information in every frame.

Comment: ok i see! Are there any Events when Encoding is finished? it would be great to run a php-script after Encoding! At the Moment i start ffmpeg Encoding async in my php script

Comment: You have asked 7 question on the site and have accepted zero answers. People are not going to be willing to continue assisting you until you acknowledge their work.

Comment: mkv works aswell but flv is better if mp4 is needed because you can copy codes and get an mp4 from it.